# Implementing a GObject interface in C++

Tags: c++, glib, gtkmm

I try to implement a GType interface in C++ using Glibmm (part of Gtkmm). The object will be passed to an API in C. Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/documentation.html) for gtkmm does not cover many details of how it wraps the GObject system.

What I have so far:

```
class MonaCompletionProvider : public gtksourceview::SourceCompletionProvider, public Glib::Object
{
    public:
        MonaCompletionProvider();
        virtual ~MonaCompletionProvider();

        Glib::ustring get_name_vfunc() const;
        // ... and some more
}
```

All method and constructor implementations are empty. The code is used like this:

```
Glib::RefPtr<MonaCompletionProvider> provider(new MonaCompletionProvider());
bool success = completion->add_provider(provider);
```

`success` will be false after executing this code and the following message appears in the command line:

> (monagui:24831):
>   GtkSourceView-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_source_completion_add_provider:
>   assertion
>   `GTK_IS_SOURCE_COMPLETION_PROVIDER
>   (provider)' failed

It seems that the underlying `gobj()` is not aware that it is supposed to implement this interface. If the class does not derive from `Glib::Object`, `gobj()` even returns null. I hope that I do not have to write a GObject implementing this interface in C manually.

So what is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance.

PS: For those who are interested: [SourceCompletionProvider](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceviewmm/stable/classgtksourceview_1_1SourceCompletionProvider.html)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-wrapping-c-libraries.html.en) is what you've been looking for about how gtkmm wraps the GObject system

Comment: I have a related issue trying to subclass Gst::AudioSink in gstreamermm - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986814/interfacing-gobject-with-c
Is there anything that better describes the mapping gmmproc is trying to create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

Class definition (order of subclasses matters):

```
class MonaCompletionProvider : public Glib::Object, public gtksourceview::SourceCompletionProvider {
...
```

Constructor (again, order matters):

```
MonaCompletionProvider::MonaCompletionProvider() :
    Glib::ObjectBase(typeid(MonaCompletionProvider)),
    Glib::Object(),
    gtksourceview::SourceCompletionProvider() {
...
```

Solution found by inspecting how it has been done in [Guikachu](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/guikachu/trunk/src/menu-win-treemodel.cc?view=log).

Comment: Sorry, SO urges me to accept one answer, even if it is my own (doesn't give points though)