# interfacing gobject with C++

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gtkmm, gobject

I’m trying to create a custom audio sink plugin for gstreamer using the Gst::AudioSink as a base class. For me this involves multiple learning curves as I’m new to gstreamer, gstreamermm and gobject. Also I have no background or real interest in gtkmm as I’m not working on GUI code at present.

I am trying to create a class along the lines of:

```
class MyAudioSink: public Gst::AudioSink
{
public:
    explicit MyAudioSink(MyAudioSink *gobj);
    virtual ~MyAudioSink();

    static void class_init(Gst::ElementClass<MyAudioSink> *klass);

    virtual int write_vfunc(gpointer data, guint length) override;
    virtual void reset_vfunc();
};
```

I seem to missing some magic in the *class_init()* function that should link the base class functions to the virtual functions in MyAudioSink.
In C we would do something like:

```
  GObjectClass *gobject_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass);
  GstAudioSinkClass *audio_sink_class = GST_AUDIO_SINK_CLASS (klass);
  audio_sink_class->write = GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR (myaudiosink_write);
```

I don’t really grok the C++ binding to gobject.
What is the equivalent for linking to the C++ virtual function hierarchy?

I got the impression from Marcin’s video https://gstconf.ubicast.tv/videos/gstreamermm-c-way-of-doing-gstreamer-based-applications/ that the virtual functions should be invoked automatically.

I can create a half usable (doesn’t handle things like EOS) plugin by adding:

```
   add_pad(sinkpad = Gst::Pad::create(get_pad_template("sink"), "sink"));
   sinkpad->set_chain_function(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyAudioSink::chain));
```

But I don't think a sink should have a chain function.

I've also asked this question on the gtkmm mailing list. If I get an answer there I will post it here.

For MyAudioSink I get a class hierarchy of:

> GObject  +----GInitiallyUnowned
> +----GstObject
> +----GstElement
> +----myaudiosink

Rather than:

> GObject  +----GInitiallyUnowned
> +----GstObject
> +----GstElement
> +----GstBaseAudioSink
> +----GstAudioSink
> +----myaudiosink

I suspect this is the essence of my problem.

For the audiofilter example Marcin mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997751/1569204) I get a class hierachy of:

> GObject  +----GInitiallyUnowned
> +----GstObject
> +----GstElement
> +----GstBaseTransform
> +----GstAudioFilter
> +----myaudiofilter

Comment: @Mgetz Why? `Glib::Object` is already the ultimate base in the class hierarchy. What would adding a 2nd copy solve, rather than make worse?

Comment: class_init has nothing to do with virtual functions. It is described [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseSink.html). You should not call any set_*_function there.

Comment: That is true for wrappers created using glibmm but not for gobject classes written in C. If you create an element using gst-element-maker the resulting code has boiler plate to set up the gobject virtual function pointers. E.g. gst-element-maker demosink audiosink
gives you gstdemosink.c containing:

`gst_demosink_class_init (GstDemosinkClass * klass)
 {
        GstAudioSinkClass *audio_sink_class = GST_AUDIO_SINK_CLASS (klass);

    audio_sink_class->open = GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR (gst_demosink_open);
`

Comment: But it is correct to say that it is not true for static methods in mm wrapper classes. 
In both cases the class_init is for meta data about the class. I'd say meta-class but that may come to mean something else in c++ in the not too distant future.

Comment: Yes but we're talking about C++, the C level callbacks are set up by the base class and the actual dispatch is taken care of by the virtual functions mechanism.

Comment: The problem for me was not the C++ side but the gobject side. How mm wrappers work is not so well documented. As I new user I inferred that the static class_init function matches the <classname>_class_init you produce in C. It does but glibmmproc takes care of the vfunc boilerplate ...unless it doesn't work for some reason that leaves a new user scratching his head. It was far from obvious that adding static method called get_base_type() broke this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that much of my troubles were caused by cutting and pasting
this into MyAudioSink class:

```
static GType get_base_type()
    {
       return Element::get_base_type();
    }
```

This had the effect of telling gobject that my class is based on *gstElement* which was wrong.
I thought it was some innocent cast like incantation.
This shows the perils of cut and paste but more than that the perils of coding blindly.
I was also guilty of oversimplifying the sample code I pasted here such that no-one my question doesn't show the problem.

That fixes my problem but does not answer my question.
I will try to summarise that below.

**"What is the equivalent for linking to the C++ virtual function hierarchy?"**

To create a wrapper to a gobject class the normal process is to use [glibmmproc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-wrapping-c-libraries.html.en).
The wrapper is defined by files with extension .hg and .ccg from which the C++ interface and a *gobject* wrapper are generated.

For example to wrap a gobject classs *foo* you might create Foo.hg and Foo.ccg.
*glibmmproc* would then generate Foo.h and Foo.cc.
Foo.cc includes most of your definition of the Foo class but with
an additional gobject wrapper *Foo_class*.

*Foo_class* is a gobject class which wraps gobject virtual functions (vfunc_callbacks) and forwards them to Foo
allowing derived classes of Foo to use C++ inheritance and C++ virtual functions.
The boilerplate is hidden and a C++ developer need for the most part only worry about the C++ interface provided by Foo.h

One way to understand the internals is to build gstreamermm from source and study the code generated by glibmmproc.
For my case this would be: gstreamermm/audiosink.cc & gstreamermm/audiosink.h generated from 
src/audiosink.ccg and src/audiosink.hg

So how *does* the derived C++ class register itself?

- *Gst::ElementFactory::register_element()* - registers the class with gstreamer
- *Gst::register_mm_type* - records the inheritance relationship

See your local /usr/include/gstreamermm-1.0/gstreamermm/register.h for the implementation

*Glib::ObjectBase(typeid (MyAudioSink))* is not required in my case as I am not using multiple inheritance. However it is critical in other applications which do. See for example [Implementing a custom gtkmm treemodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578416/implementing-a-custom-gtkmm-treemodel)

Answer (score 1):

You can find examples of writing your own plugin in the repository: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gstreamermm/tree/tests/plugins/derivedfrombasetransform.h

In general, your header looks ok, and full implementation should look (more or less) like that:

```
class MyAudioSink: public Gst::AudioSink
{
public:
    explicit MyAudioSink(KantarAudioSink *gobj)
        : Glib::ObjectBase(typeid (MyAudioSink)),
          Gst::AudioSink(gobj) {}

    static void class_init(Gst::ElementClass<MyAudioSink> *klass)
    {
        // Y
        klass->set_metadata("longname", "classification", "description", "author");

        klass->add_pad_template(Gst::PadTemplate::create("sink", Gst::PAD_SINK, Gst::PAD_ALWAYS, Gst::Caps::create_any()));
    }

    virtual int write_vfunc(gpointer data, guint length) override {}
    virtual void reset_vfunc() {}
};
```

Very recently we had a bug report when someone posted very nice, tiny example of audiofilter plugin, you can use it as an example for your project as well: https://bug794249.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=369564

If this doesn't work, feel free to file a bug here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gstreamermm

Comment: My code is as your example. The myaudiofilter you post has the expected class hierarchy but myaudiosink does not. It seems to inherit directly from GstElement. I think that my be the cause of my problem. I assumed it was a usage error on my part. Is it in fact a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "expected class hierarchy" - your element inherits from Gst::AudioSink, which is correct.

Comment: In C++ yes but in Gobject it didn't because I copied and pasted a static get_base_type() method as per my answer below.